# O que fazer quando acho uma pergunta ou resposta com palavrões?

Tags: debate

Vez ou outra, meio que na zoeira, faço umas pesquisa com coisas engraças no site só pra me divertir.

Acabei me deparando com alguns palavrões em algumas perguntas.

Eu sei que (aparentemente) a intenção da pessoa que colocou o trecho do código abaixo com a palavra de baixo calão não teve a intenção de ofender ninguém, mas me pergunto se não fica feio para o site deixar esse tipo de coisa, como na imagem abaixo.

[image]

- O que vocês acham? Perguntas com palavrões deveriam ser editada?
- Eles são negativos em algum aspecto para o site?

Comment: **Nota**: Não estou ofendido com nada, só queria tirar essa dúvida mesmo...

Comment: Sim, eu sei: mais feio que o palavrão, é usar PHP, como na imagem acima :D

Comment: Mais feio que usar o PHP é postar imagem com código. :-þ

Comment: Já tive problemas uma vez quando uma dessas exceções estourou na cara do cliente.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

De forma geral se o palavrão é gratuito, não ajuda no contexto, e não faz parte de uma piada muito boa, eu acho que é melhor retirar. Mas se não tirar e não está ofendendo ninguém também não acho que seja um problema.

Aqui só tem adultos ou pré-adultos, de acordo com o termo de uso. Palavrão está na cultura geral das pessoas. Na verdade a percepção ruim está na cabeça de quem lê. Bunda não é pior que bumbum e provavelmente é pior que glúteo, mas há uma percepção que o primeiro é feio de dizer e escrever. Sei lá porque. Não gosto de atos irracionais.

Por outro lado **podemos** facilitar para quem não gosta de ver essas coisas.

Trocar fudeu por ferrou pra mim dá na mesma. Teria que trocar por algo mais "limpo". Para algumas pessoas basta por um *fucked* ou *gefickt* ou *baisée* ou *scopata* ou *jodido* ou *becerdin* ou трахал ou *مارس الجنس* ou *πατήσαμε* ou *性交* ou *ақылды* ou *ระยำ*.

Comment: Pra quem curtir o centro-leste europeu: _Kurwa!_

Comment: Não se esqueça da Rússia Блядь @JeffersonQuesado

Answer (score 8):

O programador tarde da noite tentando depurar um programa na época que 
não havia depurador. A única saída era colocar mensagens para que mostrasse 
o caminho que o fluxo tinha seguido em função da opção escolhida.

E como era tarde da noite e já sem criatividade para distinguir as mensagens
uma das outras começou a escrever palavrões.

Depois de alguns ajustes tudo estava funcionando corretamente. Tirou rapidamente as mensagens compilou, mandou o programa para o cliente e foi embora para casa.

Chegando no escritório atrasado na manhã seguinte, alguém avisou que o seu telefone já havia tocado muito. Quando atendeu, era o cliente da noite anterior. 
Então rapidamente perguntou:

```
 - E o programa está funcionando?
```

No que o cliente responde:

```
 - Funcionando esta, mas agora ele não para de me mandar pra puta que o pariu.
```

> **Moral da estória: Não é uma boa prática.**

Comment: Eu queria poder favoritar respostas.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk bela história